# Way to generate Gson in Java

Tags: java, json

I looking for the best solution to generate Gson in Java:

For example I want to get String like:

```
{
   "mainContainer":{
      "firstContainer":{
         "value":"1"
      },
      "secondContainer":{
         "value":"2"
      }
   }
}
```

The first way (faster to implement) it to use `JsonBuilderFactory`:

```
JsonBuilderFactory factory = Json.createBuilderFactory(config);
JsonObject value = factory.createObjectBuilder()
     .add("mainContainer", factory.createObjectBuilder()
         .add("firstContainer", factory.createObjectBuilder()
             .add("value", "1")
         .add("secondContainer", factory.createObjectBuilder()
             .add("value", "2"))
     .add("phoneNumber", factory.createArrayBuilder()))
.build();
```

and the second solution (I think it should works faster):

```
public class JsonClass {
    MainContainer mainContainer;
    public JsonClass(String projectId, String parentKey){
            mainContainer = new MainContainer(projectId, parentKey);
    }
    class MainContainer{    
        private FirstContainer firstContainer;
        private SecondContainer secondContainer;
        public MainContainer(String f, String s){
            firstContainer = new FirstContainer(f);
            secondContainer = new SecondContainer(s);
        }
        class FirstContainer{
            protected String value;
            public FirstContainer(String value){this.value = value;}
        }   
        class SecondContainer{
            private String value; 
            public SecondContainer(String value){this.value = value;}
        }
    }
}
```

and then:
`String myJson = gson.toJson(new JsonClass("1","2"));`

What solution is better? I dont care about implementation time, just about works time.

Comment: maybe create a simple test, run them and compare?

Comment: http://www.lshift.net/blog/2011/12/28/benchmarking-simple-json-generation-in-java/